# How to have git location in one location and have code in another

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm using git for windows : http://windows.github.com/

My 'default storage directory' is set to : 'C:\Users\Documents\GitHub' :

[image]

but my codebase is located at c:\workspaces\myproject

How do I link the codebase with the git repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub for Windows lets you drag and drop your local repositories into the application. Navigate to the directory containing your repository and then drag the folder onto the open GitHub for Windows window. That will add the repository to GitHub for Windows without moving the folder.